# The area of a unit disk is $2\pi$? (NIntegrate over a numerical region)

Tags: numerical-integration, regions, finite-element-method

**FINAL EDIT:** *The "curious behavior" is, as explained by **user21**, due to the fact that `ImplicitRegion` decides the `RegionDimension` according to the form of the input.  If you are interested in a workaround for the issue, see also the post of **M. Stern**.  Mathematica support agrees that the questions surrounding this behavior have been answered by the contributors to this post.  Thanks to all!*

Can anyone explain the following curious behavior?  I first integrate over a disk, and get the expected answer:

```
NIntegrate[1, {x, y} ∈  Disk[]]
```

> `3.14159`

Now I construct a numerical region and recalculate:

```
Needs["NDSolve`FEM`"]
inDisk[x_?NumericQ, y_?NumericQ] := x^2 + y^2 <= 1
nrDisk = 
  ToNumericalRegion[ImplicitRegion[inDisk[x, y] == True, {{x, -1, 1}, {y, -1, 1}}]];
NIntegrate[1, {x, y} ∈  nrDisk]
```

> `6.28054`

The answer is approximately twice what it should be.  Any ideas?

Bonus points:  If I define the disk another way, why does `NIntegrate` just spit it back?

```
r2Disk[x_?NumericQ, y_?NumericQ] := x^2 + y^2
nrDisk = 
  ToNumericalRegion[ImplicitRegion[r2Disk[x, y] <= 1, {{x, -1, 1}, {y, -1, 1}}]];
NIntegrate[1, {x, y} ∈  nrDisk]
```

> `NIntegrate[1, {x, y} ∈ nrDisk]`

Comment: The problem seems to be due to the fact that `ImplicitRegion[]` is unable to handle pure Boolean-valued functions like your `inDisk[]`.

Comment: I get the expected result ( 10.1 )

Comment: @J.M. Thanks, this and your posted answer seem like key insights.  Yet `ConstantRegionQ[ImplicitRegion[x^2 + y^2 <= 1, {{x, -1, 1}, {y, -1, 1}}]]` returns True.  What is the technical difference between the expression `x^2 + y^2 <= 1` and a pure Boolean-valued function?

Comment: @george2079 I am using Mathematica 11.1.1.0.

Comment: Nothing, supposedly. I'd report this to support were I you. (Also, it's m_goldberg who posted an answer, not me. :))

Comment: @J.M. Thanks, and sorry for the name confusion :).  One more question --
 in such cases (when one decides to forward the issue to support) is it appropriate to mark a question as answered?

Comment: One way to proceed would be to post the reply you got from support after reporting this issue as an answer to your question.

Comment: Edited question for language: "boolean function" $\rightarrow$ "boolean-valued function" to avoid confusion.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**The circumference of a unit disk is 2π.**

When you hide the internal of the function and the `==` is the only thing `ImplicitRegion` does see it tries to construct a region with `RegionDimension` 1:

```
Needs["NDSolve`FEM`"]
inDisk[x_?NumericQ, y_?NumericQ] := x^2 + y^2 <= 1
nrDisk = ToNumericalRegion[
   ImplicitRegion[inDisk[x, y] == True, {{x, -1, 1}, {y, -1, 1}}]];
2 Pi - NIntegrate[1, {x, y} \[Element] nrDisk]

0.00264963
```

What will work better in this case is to use:

```
mesh = ToElementMesh[
   ImplicitRegion[
    If[inDisk[x, y], 1, -1] > 0, {{x, -1, 1}, {y, -1, 1}}]];
Pi - NIntegrate[1, {x, y} \[Element] mesh]
7.120859435438831`*^-7
```

Note that since there is no symbolic region associated with the mesh it's not really necessary to put the mesh in a `NumericalRegion`.

You can do this:

```
nr = ToNumericalRegion[
   ImplicitRegion[
    If[inDisk[x, y], 1, -1] > 0, {{x, -1, 1}, {y, -1, 1}}]];
ToElementMesh[nr]
Pi - NIntegrate[1, {x, y} \[Element] nr]
3.9561815157185265`*^-7
```

I'd need to look at why one needs to help `NIntegrate` with the numerical region in this case by calling `ToElementMesh` prior to calling `NIntegrate`.

There is a suggestion that `ImplicitRegion` should be able handle boolean region specifications better but that's out of my control so I can not say when and if this will come.

Comment: +1 for pointing out that it's the circumference. When you try different radii r it becomes obvious that the result is proportional to r instead of r^2.

Comment: Thanks @user21, I think this basically resolves the question.  I found a similar workaround, but defined a separate function `r2Disk ` that returns a smooth numerical value, which can be compared with `0`.  (I assumed that `ImplicitRegion` would appreciate a smooth function, but apparently it is just as happy with your step function.)  By the way, is there any way you know of to "inform" `ImplicitRegion` that it should try to construct a 2D region (other than giving it an inequality as input)?

Comment: @Will.Mo, no, there is no way to "inform" `ImplicitRegion` about that.

Answer (score 14):

According to the documentation of [`ToNumericalRegion`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ToNumericalRegion.html):

> The region r should be a constant region for which ConstantRegionQ gives True.

However,

```
Needs["NDSolve`FEM`"]
inDisk[x_?NumericQ, y_?NumericQ] := x^2 + y^2 <= 1
r = ToNumericalRegion[ImplicitRegion[inDisk[x, y] == True, {{x, -1, 1}, {y, -1, 1}}]];
ConstantRegionQ @ r
```

> `False`

so your region definition doesn't meet the requirements of `ToNumericalRegion`.

The following works.

```
r = ImplicitRegion[x^2 + y^2 <= 1, {{x, -1, 1}, {y, -1, 1}}];
ConstantRegionQ @ r
```

> `True`

```
Area @ r
```

> `π`

```
NIntegrate[1, {x, y} ∈ r]
```

> `3.14159`

Comment: one could add that also `DiscretizeRegion` gives a workaround: `nrDisk = DiscretizeRegion[
   ImplicitRegion[r2Disk[x, y] <= 1, {{x, -1, 1}, {y, -1, 1}}], 
   MaxCellMeasure -> 10, AccuracyGoal -> 7];`

Comment: Thanks very much!  However, the explicit boolean expression within `ImplicitRegion` is, unfortunately, what I'm trying to avoid.  I'm interested in using a more complicated boolean function that cannot be entered this way.

Comment: @M.Stern You cannot discretize a region that does not satisfy `ConatantRegionQ`.

Comment: it seems your first `ConstantRegionQ` should be on the `ImplicitRegion` not on the result of `ToNumericalRegion`.   (That said I also get `False` in 10.1 even though it "works".)  In any case its no excuse to produce a patently wrong result.

Comment: @M.Stern Your workaround is helpful for me.  Interestingly, it does not work for the slightly different expression `nrDisk = DiscretizeRegion[
   ImplicitRegion[inDisk[x, y] == True, {{x, -1, 1}, {y, -1, 1}}], 
   MaxCellMeasure -> 10, AccuracyGoal -> 7];`.  However, I may be able to use your form.

Comment: @m_goldberg Thanks also for your insight about `ToNumericalRegion`.  The mystery seems to remain as to why `ImplicitRegion` is unable to produce a well-formed region (one that passes the `ConatantRegionQ` test) from a general Boolean function.  I will forward this issue to support.

Comment: @Will.Mo. You are aware, are you not, that `ImplicitRegion[inDisk[x, y] == True` is not a boolean function?

Comment: @m_goldberg actually no, I did not realize that.  I only thought it had to be a function that returns a Boolean value.  My first try was simply to put `ImplicitRegion[inDisk[x, y]`, since this function already does this, but Mathematica complains "inDisk[x,y] should be a Boolean combination of equations, inequalities, and Element statements."  Anyway, I'm not sure `ImplicitRegion` actually requires input that is a "Boolean function" in a more technical sense.  (I also do not notice any references to Boolean functions in the documentation for `ImplicitRegion`.)

Comment: @m_goldberg I'm reading the documentation on `BooleanFunction` and it does indeed look like something special, though I will have to study it further.

Comment: @m_goldberg FYI, I updated the nomenclature in the question: "boolean function" → "boolean-valued function" to avoid confusion.

Answer (score 7):

I noticed that `ContourPlot` does an awesome job discretizing the region. I don't know how this scales and how complicated your real problem is, but for the disk it works quite well:

`ContourPlot` excludes complex numbers from the region by default, so a convenient way to plot the region is to set the function value to the imaginary unit if the point is outside the region. Then we can get the mesh by using `DiscretizeGraphics`.

```
inDisk[x_?NumericQ, y_?NumericQ] := x^2 + y^2 <= 1;
mr = DiscretizeGraphics@
   ContourPlot[
    Piecewise[{{0, inDisk[x, y]}}, I], {x, -1, 1}, {y, -1, 1}, 
    Mesh -> All, PlotPoints -> 15]
```

[image]

If we want we can simplify the mesh:

```
simplemr = 
  TriangulateMesh[mr, MaxCellMeasure -> Infinity, 
   PerformanceGoal -> "Speed"]
```

[image]

And then integrate over this region:

```
NIntegrate[1, {x, y} ∈ simplemr]
```

> 3.14027

Not perfect, but close.

**Edit:** A cleaner solution might be to use `RegionFunction` instead of the imaginary unit, for example:

```
inDisk[x_?NumericQ, y_?NumericQ, f_] := x^2 + y^2 <= 1;
mr = BoundaryDiscretizeGraphics@
   ContourPlot[0, {x, -1, 1}, {y, -1, 1}, PlotPoints -> 5, 
    MaxRecursion -> 6, RegionFunction -> inDisk];
NIntegrate[1, {x, y} ∈ mr]
```

> 3.14118

Note that I added an argument `f` to `inDisk`, because that's the form `RegionFunction` expects. Also `BoundaryDiscretizeGraphics` should suffice here. Larger values of `MaxRecursion` can make the mesh region more accurate.

Comment: Slick tricks!  It seems yet another one way is `RegionPlot`, i.e. `mr = DiscretizeGraphics[
 RegionPlot[inDisk[x, y] == True, {x, -1, 1}, {y, -1, 1}]]`.  I think the key idea here is that Mathematica's plotting routines are more robust/efficient than `ImplicitRegion`, which is currently a bit delicate.

Comment: Yes, here's another example of delicate behavior: `Area[ImplicitRegion[(x^2 + y^2 <= 1) == 
   True, {{x, -1, 1}, {y, -1, 1}}]]` gives 0, without complaining. Interestingly while you would expect `RegionPlot` and `ContourPlot` to work similar internally, it's easier to approach the correct value of $\pi$ with `ContourPlot`...

Comment: Yet another solution a lá @M.Stern can be found if one can replace the condition with a smooth function.  Define `r2Disk[x_?NumericQ, y_?NumericQ] := x^2 + y^2`.  Then `nrDisk = ToNumericalRegion[
  ImplicitRegion[r2Disk[x, y] <= 1, {{x, -1, 1}, {y, -1, 1}}]]`.  Then `meshDisk = ToElementMesh[nrDisk];`.  Then check the accuracy: `Pi - NIntegrate[1, {x, y} ∈ meshDisk]`.  This yields $\sim 10^{-7}$ error, i.e. the same as a "perfect" `Disk[]`.

Comment: That is, the same error as with a mesh generated from a `Disk[]`.  NIntegrate directly over a `Disk[]` is better, $\sim 10^{-9}$.